# Inequality symbols in Japanese writing

Tags: mathematics, symbols

In English, when we wish to write a non-strict mathematical inequality, we will write something like this:

> x ≤ 3 or y ≥ 5

In Japanese writing, however, I have also seen the symbol ≦ used to mean "less than or equal to". Which of ≤ and ≦ is more common in Japanese usage? I would be interested to know about any differences that exist across various media/genres of writing, e.g. news reports vs. scholarly papers vs. textbooks.

Comment: Do we have a tag for questions about 記号 / other symbols in Japanese writing? I took a brief look at the tags list but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't see any tags specifically about symbols, but you could always make one :-)

Comment: I'd be curious to know the Japanese translations for "less than or equal to" and "greater than or equal to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

≦ is used everywhere in Japan, unless it's a paper written in English.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, by "everywhere", presumably you mean "everywhere *in Japan*"?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: No I mean, in all domains e.g. school text books, books, company reports, Japanese journals etc.

Comment: Revise my question :) -- "everywhere *in Japanese*?" I'm not that familiar with the typography conventions of the non-English-writing world, and your answer above sounds like only English writing uses the ≤ while all other languages use the ≦. Is that your intended meaning?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: Oh no, I meant in Japan. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

I remember I only used ≦ in elementary and middle schools, but in collage (computer science major), everyone switched to ≤. I forgot about high school. So I'm sure both are used, but unless it's something scientific, I think most people use ≦.